# Returning a structure results in gibberish

Tags: c, function, struct, structure

I'm using structures in C and when I try to return a structure from a function it always results in gibberish when I try to print the contents of that structure in main.
Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct etudiant
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
typedef struct etudiant ETD;

ETD ajouter_etd()
{
    ETD e;
    scanf("%i%i%i", e.a, e.b, e.c);
    return e;
}

void main()
{
    ETD e;
    e = ajouter_etd();
    printf("%i%i%i", e.a, e.b, e.c);
}
```

Comment: When you compiled with warnings enabled, what warnings did you get?

Comment: @Dhia Ammar Use scanf("%i%i%i", &e.a, &e.b, &e.c);

Comment: Compile your code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass the addresses of your variables to `scanf` as it needs to know where in memory to place the results of its conversions. This is done with the [address-of operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_member_access#Address_of) (`&`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct etudiant {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} ETD;

ETD ajouter_etd(void)
{
    ETD e;
    scanf("%i%i%i", &e.a, &e.b, &e.c);
    return e;
}

int main(void)
{
    ETD e;
    e = ajouter_etd();
    printf("%i%i%i\n", e.a, e.b, e.c);
}
```